# JS Function to navigate to the new View MVC C# not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

This is my details page in controllers and wanting to click on the button and navigate to the detail page (eg. /ExpiationOffeces/Details/id)

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.ExpiationOffences == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var expiationOffence = await _context.ExpiationOffences
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ExpiationOffenceCode == id);
            if (expiationOffence == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(expiationOffence);
        }
```

And adding the JS function to run but it just shows (/ExpiationOffeces/Details), properly it's not working, my JS function

```
function foo(id) {
    window.location = "@Url.Action('Details', 'ExpiationOffences', new { id = '__id__'})" + id;
}
```

And my index view

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card mt-sm-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Expiation Code: @item.ExpiationOffenceCode</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Expiation Offence Description: <br> @item.ExpiationOffenceDescription</p>
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ExpiationOffenceCode" class="btn btn-outline-warning d-flex justify-content-center" target="_blank">View Detail</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

What should I do to redirect to the detail page?

Comment: Why not simply use the anchor tag helper? `<a asp-controller="ExpiationOffences" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="__id__...">View Detail</a>`

Comment: I would love to use but the requirement asked to use JS then

Comment: What is the id that you need to pass to the function? Is it the button's id or something else?

Comment: asp-route-id="@item.ExpiationOffenceCode" is the id I need to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code like below:

```
<a onclick="foo(1)" class="btn btn-outline-warning d-flex justify-content-center">View Detail</a>

<script>
    //pass id in url
    function foo(id) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "ExpiationOffences", new {id = "_id" })';
        var urlWithId = url.replace('_id', id);
        window.location.href = urlWithId;
    }
</script>
```

result:

[image]

Besides, you can use `asp-route-id`

```
<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ExpiationOffenceCode">Details</a> |
```

You can have a look at [Part 6, controller methods and views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.

**Update**

> id in detail page is string

Change the onclick like `onclick="foo('@item.ExpiationOffenceCode')"`

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I think I have tried this and it is also not working.

Comment: http://localhost:5113/@Url.Action("Details",%20"ExpiationOffences",%20new%20%7Bid%20=%20"1"%20%7D), the url show like this. And the id in detail page is tring. so how can I fix this?

Comment: This answer should work, I tested it and works for me. Only thing I would change is put the script inside `@section Scripts { ... }`. Did you notice that he changed single quotes to double quotes for the `Url.Action` parameters?

Comment: @AnhHuyNguyen Have a  look at my update.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. And if I want to open it in the new tab, which attributes I should add?

Comment: @AnhHuyNguyen   If you want to open it in the new tab, add `target="_blank"`  is ok.